# Java receive file from http request

Tags: java, servlets

I should write servlet that receive File from request. I want to store this file in local dir on the server. How can I do that? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fileUpload from apache found [here](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload).

Comment: This won't help as the OP wants to download a file and not upload.

Comment: If you mean to download it from your application then you can use the FileUpload to upload it and save it wherever and then there are plenty of articles and ways of how to download it. The Elite Gentleman indicates a fine article right here and here is another link: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4629

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman:  It sounds like a file upload from the question.

Comment: Nope!! In the FileServlet class the doGet method of @The Elite Gentleman's link, DOWNLOADS a file from the server. this link right here: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html#FileServletServingFromAbsolutePath . Give it a try if you like.

Comment: @Don Roby, the first time I read it, it sounded like he wants to get a file from an HTTP request. I reupdated my post.

Comment: Oh ok!! to tell you truth I thought the same thing!

Comment: @gred Can you please write more about the `fileUpload`? If the link becomes obsolete tomorrow, this answer will be of no use to the future readers :(

Answer (score 2):

[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) wrote an excellent blog on [FileServlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html). This will help you.

Oops, the above-mentioned article shows you how to do file download, to do file upload, use the [Apache FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) library instead.